# Setting custom kernel for CNN in pytorch

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, pytorch, torch

Is there a way to specify our own custom kernel values for a convolution neural network in pytorch? Something like [kernel_initialiser](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/api_docs/python/tf/layers/conv2d_transpose) in tensorflow? Eg. I want a 3x3 kernel in `nn.Conv2d` with initialization so that it acts as a identity kernel -

`0 0 0`
`0 1 0`
`0 0 0`

(this will effectively return the same output as my input in the very first iteration)

My non-exhaustive research on the subject -

I could use [nn.init](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/init.html) but it only has some pre-defined kernel initialisaition values.

I tried to follow the discussion on their [official thread](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/weight-initilzation/157/2) but it doesn't suit my needs.

I might have missed something in my research please feel free to point out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [ptrblck](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/setting-custom-kernel-for-cnn-in-pytorch/27176/4?u=markroxor) I was able to solve it.
I can define a new convolution layer as `conv` and as per the example I can set the identity kernel using -

```
weights = ch.Tensor([[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]]).unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0)
weights.requires_grad = True


conv = nn.Conv2d(1, 1, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False)

with ch.no_grad():
    conv.weight = nn.Parameter(weights)
```

I can then continue to use `conv` as my regular `nn.Conv2d` layer.

Answer (score 1):

I think an easier solution is to :

```
    deconv = nn.ConvTranspose2d(
        in_channels=channel_dim, out_channels=channel_dim,
        kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=stride,
        bias=False, padding=1, output_padding=1
    )
    deconv.weight.data.copy_(
        get_upsampling_weight(channel_dim, channel_dim, kernel_size)
    )
```

in other words use copy_